# MVC creating SQL views vs. putting calculations in the controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, view, one-to-many

I applied for a job, they required me to create a small MVC app before interview which I did. They rejected it saying that I had used bad practices. Please help me figure out what I did wrong!

The task involved a simple database with a `Product` and a load of `Sales` (a one to many).

I had to:

1. display a list of products with total sales
2. display and allow edition and deletion of the sales

My solution:

1. create a left joined SQL view which used a group and join to itself to get the sale totals. This table had one row per product
2. Create an inner joined SQL view with all of the product and sales data. This had one row per sale.

For #1, I just rendered out the view

For #2, I had to render out product details and sales details (a one to many on a single page) so I did the following in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
     // get details for the selected product
     var product = db.ProductsWithTotals.Where(q => q.ProductId == id).Single();
     ViewData["CatalogueNumber"] = product.CatalogueNumber;
     ViewData["Title"] = product.Title;
     ViewData["Artist"] = product.Artist;
     ViewData["TotalSold"] = product.TotalSold;
     ViewData["ProductId"] = product.ProductId;

     // then pass its sales lines to the view
     var salesLines = db.SalesLineDetails.Where(q => q.ProductId == id);
     return View(salesLines);
}
```

If anyone could explain how I could have done this more gracefully, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you find out from those guys what they didn't like about your approach? I find it quite sensible and a good idea, honestly...

Comment: The only "bad" thing I can see is that your controller is tied with L2S and you won't be able to switch to a different data access component, but I woulnd't consider this bad practice for an interview question. If the person rejecting your application wasn't considerate to explain what he / she thought it was wrong, it's probably better you didn't get the job. Working with this kind of people it's a pain...

Comment: Many thanks for the replies. It is encouraging to know there is nothing  fundamentally wrong with my design. The agent did try and press them for a reason but all I received was: 

“The standard of coding was not high enough. It looked like he only had a very basic understanding of some of the techniques being used and there was some odd and unnecessary code which looked like it might be boiler-plate, or copied from elsewhere.” 

The task was a small project with a shot deadline so I thought it ok to use the L2S classes to save time. Dradu, I think your right, this was probably a blessing.

Comment: The only potential problem here is. if I have a log tearm development in mind meaning change-ing databases (in tearms of data providers) and table structures. From that perspective it is better imo:
**1)** a query with a group and join not a view and then display that
**2)** An approach where user first needs ot select some sort of input parameters for sales for inastance date filters from->to and/or product filter 
and then filter them out and then edit the selected one cos it will reduce the workload.

But as allready suggested I don't see any fundamental flaws there for a simple display app

Comment: Please show us the tables and views. I can think of few things you could do better. If you could add more detail to your question then I could give you a detailed answer. FWIW: The title to your question does not accurately describe the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I personally would have done differently is:

- Use EF (but yeah, L2S is fine for a quickie like this)
- Create a ViewModel class for the details View. I use ViewData as sparingly as possible.

But yeah, nothing bad here and I agree that it was probably not a good place to work at. People also tend to make up vague reasons if they didn't want to say they didn't like your face.

/shrug